# How to monitor the connectivity between multiple machine

Tags: nagios

I am using Nagios to monitor my servers and I have an need to monitor the inter connectivity between different servers. For example assume that I have three servers A, B & C and all of these servers are already monitored by nagios using check_ping plugin.

Now I want to check connectivity between these three servers internally, I mean from

> server A,  B & C should be reachable, likewise from B,  A & C should
>   be reachable , same for server C

What is the way to do this using nagios.

```
Server A - can ping to servers B&C 
Server B - can ping to servers A&C 
Server C - can ping to servers B&C
```

I have tried with multiple ping command in server A, but it is not helpful because i cant able to find out whether server B/C is not reacheable from A

```
command[check_ping]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H 10.16.15.137 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5 
command[check_ping]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H 10.18.42.125 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5 


where
10.16.15.137 -> SERVER B 
10.18.42.125 -> SERVER C
```

Comment: updated the question please check

Answer (score 2):

Install the NRPE daemon on all 3 servers, and write *different* check commands, like `check_ping_A`, `check_ping_B`, `check_ping_C`, etc., on the different servers (in the NRPE config):

```
command[check_ping_A]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H x.x.x.x -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5 
command[check_ping_B]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H y.y.y.y -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
```

You'd check B & C from A, A & C from B, etc. This is a simple approach, but it doesn't scale well.

(Or write a generic `check_ping` that takes the address as an ARG and enable NRPE argument processing. This is more flexible, but some people are uneasy with this practice.)

Then use check_nrpe on the Nagios server to check the various combinations. You can simply this slightly by using [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/discussion), especially if you want to check more than 3 servers in the future.

Comment: How Can I write  check_ping_A, check_ping_B, check_ping_C ? I mean do I need to add anything in nagios master to do this?

Comment: Answer updated with more specific example

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NRPE](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/addons.html#nrpe) on the servers to actually test the connection from there. On the nagios machine, you would use the `check_nrpe` plugin to get the results.

NRPE essentially means you run Nagios plugins locally on a monitored host and get the results back to Nagios via the NRPE protocol.